# Did not get compile error when comparing Enum with const int using Equals

Tags: c#, enums, compare, constants

C#: Code parts:

```
class ConstValues
{
   public const int NULL=1;
}

class Example
{
   private enum FormatFunction
   {
      Date,
      Unknown
   }

   ...

   FormatFunction returnValue = fn();

   ...
```

Now I have two scenarios.

When I used this way to compare my return code to a value

```
if (!returnValue.Equals(ConstValues.NULL))
{
   ...
```

I get no compile time error (and the code does not work as intended because this is a bug of mine that I missed out).

But when I change to

```
if (returnValue != ConstValues.NULL)
{
   ...
```

I get a compile time error and discover the mistake I did.

I understand that the underlying structure of an enum is int, but I would rather get a compile time error even when using Equals.

Why do the first way pass and the second don't?

Comment: There is also a method Enum.IsDefined i think it could be useful for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!=` is a language convention so this is C# specific. Calling this operator is *early bound*, in other words, it will occur at compile time.

`Equals` is a framework convention, .NET in this case, and that is bound at runtime.

When you call `!=`, the decision is made by the C# compiler during compilation so you get an error. When you call `Equals` the decision is made by the framework at runtime. Since your enum is not of type object, it will be turned into an object (boxing) and then the runtime will check if your type has overridden the `Equals` method, since you have not, it will use the default implementation.

---

`Equals` for Reference type

If the instance is a reference type, the default implementation of `Equals` checks if one object reference is the same as the other object reference. If they are the same reference, it returns true. Otherwise it returns false.

---

`Equals` for Value type

If the instance is a value type, then it will test for value equality. This is your case. It will check if the enum value you have is equal to the constant value. No error will be shown or thrown: it either equals or it does not.

Comment: Both answers are pretty much the same, but this one is more "aimed to my basic level" so I cross this one. But thx all!

Answer (score 3):

It is because default virtual Equals method is receiving **object** instead of strong typed value like in second example. It is boxed into object and will check types only in runtime.

Why it is made so? The reasoning is pretty funny - for possibility to compare cats and dogs if they walk on all fours. Compare two completely different objects by some almost identical properties.

Thing is, when you can - work with strong typed objects. This will prevent bad things from happening in compile time.